# UNIX/LINUX Recursively count

Tags: linux, unix, recursion, filter, pipe

**Recursively display the contents of files with line numbers from the lab0 directory whose name begin with 's', sort the line by name a->z, suppress the output of access errors**

This is how i tried to filter all files begin with 's':
to filter all files:
[All file from directory lab0 displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSeuj.png)
to filter all files begin with 's':
[I cannot filter whose begin with 's'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyzME.png)
to filter all files begin with another letter:
[Well it works with letter 'c'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSUMj.png)

My question is how to filter all files whose name begin with 's' and count out their content line then sort their name as quest. Thanks
*I'm learning Unix using PuTTY terminal emulator.
The commands should be used: cat, wc, ls, head, tail, echo, sort, grep*

Comment: Try `ls -1` instead of `ls -l` so you get only filenames and can filter on them. Also have a look at `find` utility.

Comment: My command `lab0$ ls -1R | grep ^- | grep \ s | wc -l | sort` displays only number 0 .

Comment: Because with -1 there is no space in front. You would use `grep ^s` instead. But `find` is the better option anyways, although not listed as a command to be used in your assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -name "s*" -type f | sort | tee /dev/tty | wc -l
```

Find all files in the current directory and child directories, starting with s and sorting the output, outputting the results to screen and counting the number of files, printing the count to screen.